# Seeking info on Exchange EWS logs in effort to determine level of compromise

Tags: security, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Good evening.
I'm investigating a compromised exchange server, and am a bit perplexed on what I'm seeing in the EWS logs (Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Logging\EWS).  The machine was compromised using the ProxyShells exploit, and was being used to send spam replies to messages.  If someone is familiar with what normal EWS logs show, I think you can be very helpful to me.  If someone knows where I can find detailed documentation on what the fields in the EWS logs mean, I'm also happy to read...

The requests come from a load balancer, so the ClientIPAddress isn't useful to me.

In the EWS logs, I see many requests that appear legitimate, with the "AuthenticatedUser" field showing domain\username.  The UserAgent field for these requests is: `Microsoft Office/16.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Microsoft Outlook 16.0.5149; Pro)` I assume this is normal activity.

On known compromised accounts, I see requests with AuthenticatedUser as either `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` or "domain\ExchangeServerName$".  The UserAgent field for these is `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML  like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36.`  In this context, the AuthenticatedUser field and UserAgent field appear suspicious.

On accounts where I'm unsure as to whether or not they are compromised, I see some events with `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` as the AuthenticatedUser, and the UserAgent as `Exchange/15.1.2242.4/ElcClient/S=MRM&BI=<LongStringOfChars>`.  The SOAP action on these is ExportItems.  I'm not certain whether this is a malicious export of email, or whether it's the Exchange Admins exporting mailboxes to restore to a clean server.

**My questions:**

Is it ever normal for "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" to be the AuthenticatedUser in the EWS logs?
Is it possible to correlate activity shown in the EWS logs with SOAP actions of GetItem or ExportItems with the actual emails or other such items in question?  I see a RequestID, and CorrelationID, but I'm uncertain as to what they might refer to.

Any help, of course, is much appreciated.  Thank you.